# How to turn off the profanity filter for the voice to text service

Tags: ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm simply trying to turn off the profanity filter for the voice to text service. I'm using a phone number to call into the service and need to keep profanity filter turned off.

Answer (score 0):

As per the API docs - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text#recognize-audio

set `profanity_filter` to `false`. How you do it will depend on your coding language. The API docs show how for each value.